# Why can't I execute systemctl commands as superuser?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, kubernetes, systemctl

I wrote a script to download and install kubernetes on an ubuntu machine.

The last part of the script would be to start the kubelet service.

```
echo "Initializing the master node"
kubeadm reset
systemctl start kubelet.service
kubeadm init
```

I am forcing the user to run the script as root user. However, when the script reaches the systemctl command, it is not able to execute it. Moreover, I tried to execute the command manually as the root user. I was not able to do so. However, I am able to execute it as a regular user.
Does anyone know why? Is there a workaround?

Comment: What permissions does the service have?

Comment: it is executable by everyone.

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround is to start the service as a regular user, even though the script runs as root. First, you need to find out who is the "original" user:

```
originalUser="$(logname 2>/dev/null)"
```

and then call the service as this user:

```
su - "$originalUser" -c "systemctl start kubelet.service"
```

Maybe that specific service is dependent on being run by an user who is not root (some programs test for that).